# How can I quickly load Google documents?

Tags: google-drive

I have some larger (~30-100 pages) Google documents that I access many times per day. Currently, the one that's about 100 pages long takes roughly 30 seconds to load, despite having very few images. This long load time is inconvenient, so I would like to see if there is a way to decrease it. Could I somehow save the documents to my computer and load them from my hard drive instead of from the Internet and just sync the changes to the Internet? If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

Turn on offline access

> You can work on files on a Chrome browser even when you’re not connected to the Internet. Chrome automatically syncs files in Drive, Docs, Sheets, and Slides so you can view and edit files offline.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2375012?hl=en

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Every time I open the documents, it just loads them like it normally does. Also, my Google Drive folder's documents just store the url of the appropriate document along with a bit of other information, instead of this actual document. How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that you must use Chrome, and must configure Drive to "Sync Google Docs, Sheets, Slides and Drawings files to this computer so that you can edit offline." in Settings.

Comment: @CLaFarge That's what I've done, and it still isn't working.